# I am not understanding why there is padding in this sign in button

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am getting this white border in my button and how do I remove it.

**My Text button**

```
TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: 51,
                  width: 113,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Sign Up!'),
                  ),
                ))
```

**My Theme class**

```
  static var darkModeAppTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      cardColor: greyColor,
      textButtonTheme: const TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(whiteColor),
              foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(blackColor))),
      inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
        fillColor: Colors.green,
        filled: true,
      ));
```

[image]

How to remove that white padding

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! When writing questions, be sure to indent the code correctly, to make it more readable and have a better chance of getting an answer. To avoid doing it manually, you can copy and paste the code like normal text in the question, then select the code and click the format code button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove this padding u can do it in **ButtonStyle**()

```
 style: ButtonStyle(
              padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.zero),// to remove that padding
                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.green),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black)),
```

you can achieve this 2 ways.

1. by removing the padding.

   ```
          TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.zero),// to remove padding
              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.red),
              foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black)),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
            ),

            height: 51,
            width: 113,
            child: Center(child: Text('Sign Up!')),
          ),),
   ```
2. By swapping the container

   ```
            Container(
            width: 113,
             height: 51,
        child: TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(

                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.green),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black)),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Center(child: Text('Sign Up!')),),
      ),
   ```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! When writing answers, make sure to indent the code correctly, to make it more readable and have a better chance of getting upvotes. To avoid doing it manually, you can copy and paste the code as normal text into your response, then select the code and click the button to format it.

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible way to fixes

1. You can remove backgroundColor from ButtonStyle
2. Add style to your Text Button

   ```
   TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 51,
          width: 113,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text('Sign Up!'),
          ),
        ),
    ),
   ```